# Sorting by key and value in case keys are equal

Tags: python, sorting, oauth

The [official oauth guide](http://www.hueniverse.com/hueniverse/2008/10/beginners-gui-1.html) makes this recommendation:

> It is important not to try and perform
>   the sort operation on some combined
>   string of both name and value as some
>   known separators (such as '=') will
>   cause the sort order to change due to
>   their impact on the string value.

If this is the case, then what would be an efficient way of doing this? A second iteration after the initial sort looking for equal keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort the list of tuples (name, value) -- Python does lexicographic ordering for you.